# timedelta in sublimetext not working

Tags: python, datetime, sublimetext2, sublimetext, timedelta

```
import datetime, getpass from datetime 
import timedelta import sublime, sublime_plugin

class TommorowCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1) } )

class YesterdayCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) } )
```

I have saved the above code as `time.py` 
and mapped the commands to hotkey to insert yesterday's and tommorow's date in the editor.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis to group the `datetime` arithmetic together:

```
{"contents": "%s" % (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))}
```

because the `+` operator has a lower precedence than the `%` operator:

```
>>> "%s" % datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' objects
>>> "%s" % (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
'2013-11-14'
```

In the first form, Python evaluated `"%s" % datetime.date.today()` *first* and then you end up adding a string and a `timedelta()` object.

You *could* just use `str()` here:

```
{"contents": str(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my query.

{"contents": str(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))}
{"contents": str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))}

Comment: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d %b %Y")
Gives me this 
Thursday, 14 Nov 2013 

Is there a way to get tommorow and yesterday in this format 
str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%A, %d %b %Y") + datetime.timedelta(days=1))

does not seem to give me my desired result 
Friday, 15 Nov 2013

Comment: Sure, call that on the result of the subtraction (so use parenthesis here too): `(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("....")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time got all my answers  :)

I have just started to fully explore sublime text and it used python for plugins , am a DotNet guy barely done any python scripting.